# Total Differentials Fluid Mechanics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, velocity, stress-strain

I'm having trouble with total differentials in relation to the attached picture (fluid deformation). I don't understand how the expressions for ${\rm d}u$ and ${\rm d}v$ come about.

It looks like $u = f(x)$ and $v = f(y)$, so i'm not sure why the incremental increases ${\rm d}u$ and ${\rm d}v$ involve partial differentials, rather than differentials of only one variable.

[image]

It's probably pretty obvious to someone in the know, all help gratefully received

Answer (score 1):

The picture itself shows it. The extreme $AD$ is moving with velocity $v$, while the other one, $BC$, is moving with a slightly greater one, namely $v+dv$, which you can write as

$v+\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} dx$, by just using the chain rule. The interpretation is logical: "the original one plus the rate of change in the $x$ direction times the distance in that direction".

The same applies for $u$ in the other one.

The point is that both sides of the volume move at different speeds, and that's why it changes its shape.

Those speeds might depend on more variables, but that's nor relevant here, since we're focusing on just an infinitesimal instant.